Databricks OutOfMemory error on code that previously worked without issue
I have a notebook in Azure Databricks that does some transformations on a bronze tier table and inserts the transformed data into a silver tier table. This notebook is used to do an initial load of the data from our existing system into our new datalake. Specifically, it converts a list of columns into individual child rows in another table (sort of a key:value pair type of table). I've been running this code for weeks without issue: same code, same data, same cluster configuration. Suddenly, I am now consistently receiving an OutOfMemory error when I execute this particular section of the notebook. The data is not overly large, and the table I'm inserting into is only 6 columns (3 integer type and 3 string type).
I've tried everything I can think of to fix the issue: batching the data, splitting the upsert into multiple calls rather than a single call with a larger dataset, tweaking configuration values, executing on larger servers. Nothing fixes it. I don't understand why code that was working for weeks with no changes on the same data and cluster configuration has suddenly stopped working. Hoping someone can help me out. I've included the original code (as well as an example of one of the code tweaks I made) to see if anyone has any suggestions.

dfCallData = fetchCallSummaryData(useArchive=False) \
                .join(_callMap, on=(col('UniqueCallID') == _callMap.systemCallId) & (_callMap.systemType != lit('NOVA')), how='inner') \
                .select(col('UniqueCallId'), col('tenantId'), col('agentId'), col('channelType'), col('callerPhone'), col('callerName'), col('terminationType'), 
                        col('callDuration'), col('transferDuration'), col('callOutcome'), col('transferReason'), col('endEvent'), col('lastStepName'), col('reportDate'), 
                        col('callInitiatedOn'), col('lastSystemUpdateOn'), col('isFirstTimeCaller'), col('isAfterHours'), col('finalStatus'), col('clk.isArchived'), 
                        col('clk.archivedOn'), col('Conversation'), col('QueueDuration'), col('AgentDuration'), col('TransferTalkDuration'), col('WhisperDuration'), 
                        col('BillingRatePerIVRMinute'), col('BillingRatePerTransferMinute'), col('BillingRatePerCall'), col('BillingGracePeriod'), col('CustomerData'), 
                        col('CustomerDataFlattened'), col('RunMode'), col('SurveyResults'), col('RedactedConversation'), col('Disposition'), col('Col1'), col('Col2'), 
                        col('Col3'), col('Col4'), col('Col5'), col('Col6'), col('Col7'), col('Col8'), col('Pub1'), col('Pub2'), col('Pub3'), col('Pub4'), col('Pub5'), 
                        col('Pub6'), col('Pub7'), col('Pub8'), col('PubBreadCrumbs'), col('PubFlattened'), col('PubLastBreadCrumb'), col('PubIntent'), 
                        col('PubAuthenticated'), col('Transcript'), col('clk.callId'))

pub_cols = ['Pub1', 'Pub2', 'Pub3', 'Pub4', 'Pub5', 'Pub6', 'Pub7', 'Pub8']

# Original method signature
def processMappedCallData(columns_to_convert:list) -> DataFrame:
    dfNewMap = spark.read.table('silver.appdata.call_data_map') \
                         .where(col('mapType') == 'columns') \
                         .alias('dm')

    dfCallDataSub = dfCallData.select('callId', 'UniqueCallId', col('agentId'), *columns_to_convert) \
                              .alias('cd')

    dfData = None
    for c in columns_to_convert:
        df = dfCallDataSub.join(dfNewMap, (col('cd.agentId') == col('dm.agentId')) & (col('dm.mapKey') == c), 'inner') \
                          .where((col(f'cd.{c}').isNotNull()) & (col(f'cd.{c}') != '')) \
                          .withColumn('callDataId', lit(None)) \
                          .withColumn('callDataType', lit('columns:mapped')) \
                          .select('callDataId', 'cd.callId', 'dm.callDataMapId', 'callDataType', lit(c).alias('legacyColumn'),  
                                  col(f'cd.{c}').alias('dataValue'))

        dfData = dfData.union(df) if dfData is not None else df

    return dfData

dfPubCols = processMappedCallData(pub_cols)
_pipeline.execute_call_data_pipeline(dfPubCols, callDataType='columns')


# Upsert
def execute_call_data_pipeline(self, dfMappedData:DataFrame, callDataType='columns:mapped'):
        dtCallData = DeltaTable.forName(self._spark, f'{self.get_catalog()}.{self.get_schema()}.call_data')
        dtCallData.alias('old').merge(
                source=dfMappedData.alias('new'),
                condition=expr('old.callDataId = new.callDataId')
        ).whenMatchedUpdate(set=
            {
                'callId': col('new.callId') if 'callId' in dfMappedData.columns else col('old.callId'),
                'callDataMapId': col('new.callDataMapId') if 'callDataMapId' in dfMappedData.columns else col('old.callDataMapId'),
                'callDataType': col('new.callDataType') if 'callDataType' in dfMappedData.columns else col('old.callDataType'),
                'legacyColumn': col('new.legacyColumn') if 'legacyColumn' in dfMappedData.columns else col('old.legacyColumn'),
                'dataValue': col('new.dataValue') if 'dataValue' in dfMappedData.columns else col('old.dataValue'),
                'isEncrypted': col('new.isEncrypted') if 'isEncrypted' in dfMappedData.columns else col('old.isEncrypted'),
                'silverUpdateOn': lit(datetime.now(timezone.utc).timestamp())
            }
        ).whenNotMatchedInsert(values=
            {
                'callId': col('new.callId'),
                'callDataMapId': col('new.callDataMapId') if 'callDataMapId' in dfMappedData.columns else lit(None),
                'callDataType': col('new.callDataType') if 'callDataType' in dfMappedData.columns else lit(callDataType),
                'legacyColumn': col('new.legacyColumn') if 'legacyColumn' in dfMappedData.columns else lit(None),
                'dataValue': col('new.dataValue'),
                'isEncrypted': col('new.isEncrypted') if 'isEncrypted' in dfMappedData.columns else lit(False),
                'silverCreateOn': lit(datetime.now(timezone.utc).timestamp())
            }
        ).execute()


Below is the change I made to the processMappedCallData() method to break the data into multiple upsert calls in smaller chunks of ~300M rows rather than one large dataframe of ~2.4B rows. Both the original and this one failed. The error is always the same: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
def processMappedCallData(columns_to_convert:list):
    dfNewMap = spark.read.table('silver.appdata.call_data_map') \
                         .where(col('mapType') == 'columns') \
                         .alias('dm')

    dfCallDataSub = dfCallData.select('callId', 'UniqueCallId', col('agentId'), *columns_to_convert) \
                              .alias('cd')

    dfData = None
    for c in columns_to_convert:
        df = dfCallDataSub.join(dfNewMap, (col('cd.agentId') == col('dm.agentId')) & (col('dm.mapKey') == c), 'inner') \
                          .where((col(f'cd.{c}').isNotNull()) & (col(f'cd.{c}') != '')) \
                          .withColumn('callDataId', lit(None)) \
                          .withColumn('callDataType', lit('columns:mapped')) \
                          .select('callDataId', 'cd.callId', 'dm.callDataMapId', 'callDataType', lit(c).alias('legacyColumn'),  
                                  col(f'cd.{c}').alias('dataValue'))
        _pipeline.execute_call_data_pipeline(df, callDataType='columns')


You mentioned that you have tried tweaking configuration values, but it's possible that you may need to adjust the Spark configurations to appropriate values. You can balance the application requirements with the available resources in the cluster, but these values shouldn't exceed 90% of the available memory and cores as viewed by YARN, and should also meet the minimum memory requirement of the Spark application.

You can calculate the total memory used by all executors and the driver as follows:
Total memory used by all executors = spark.executor.instances * (spark.executor.memory + spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead)
Total memory used by driver = spark.driver.memory + spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead
